What are alternative methods of combat if explosions like in guns are too dangerous to use because of explosive gases?
What are alternative methods of combat if explosions like in guns are too dangerous to use because of explosive gases? There are trenches and ravines in my world where the atmosphere is filled with dense highly explosive gas (I have not decided which gas yet). I have not decided where the gas comes from many its produced by dragon like fauna or the local plants. It could also just come out of the ground. Since a spark could kill everyone, guns can't be used here. With modern technology are there any other specialized weapons we might develop as alternatives to guns other than just going medieval? Pleez no magick solutions
Also, would the solution be just to stab if people had to fight in this environment? This is a near-future world

I was looking for similar questions and accidentally found mine again. I was like wow someone already asked this great. lol also I am sorry for the spelling it is something I am working on

It would help to know the time period / technology level of your world. Also, bear in mind explosive gases would possibly also be ignited by sparks from any launched projectiles striking a hard surface. So if the trenches are rocky or combatants are wearing armour, that's something to consider.

If the gas is confined to trenches and ravines and only gradually replenishes after it explodes, why would the occupants of your world not engage in controlled burns?

For future reference, Stack Exchange expects questions to be asked with the possibility of selecting one best answer. In other words, asking for an arbitrary and open-ended list of options is specifically the kind of question Stack Exchange doesn't want. See [ask] for more information. Thanks.

How are people making steel? That requires a ton of heat. If you want to skip over that, just look at any war/battle pre Agincourt in 1415.

There are too many sources of natural sparks for this to be realistic. Fires could be started by falling rocks hitting eachother and making sparks, lightning strikes, static discharges between animals, or water droplets on flammable surfaces acting as a lens and focusing light into a fire among many other sources

Laser pointer heating up the surface of the object to be destroyed would work if you weren't in a shared atmosphere...

I mean... static electricity is so rampant you don't even understand. Unless literally everyone is wearing ESD protective gear and the ground is good enough to allow for it to work... this type of situation would be avoided at all costs by anyone.

Many war tactics (widely used historically and still today) don't consist in just plain attacks, but just cutting your enemies access to the resources they need to sustain their own attacks, or their defenses, to place them in a situation where only them will be in situation of weakness or danger. This includes access to non-material resources, such as communication, education, or monitoring their environment to make predictions that are more or less reliable et benefiting to them in terms of work needed and time.

As such, non-material attacks are just social, to influence the decisions or acceptation/rebutal of any situation. Spreading fake information all around to give birth to doubts or to unsolvable questions. Similar attacks are more or less related to the definition of good and bad, as defined in politics or religion, and the perception of who can control (by their perceived presence) a larger number of people that have no real choice and cannot see any solution without a large cloud of noise. Notably propaganda is very efficient for that since long, not new but growing key of "modern" warfare.

Longbows, broadswords and bagpipes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Churchill

@Wyrsa Looks like these emanations of explosive gas are no {geological|geophysical} novelty; how did the locals adapt to them? I would expect everyone, from every surviving species, to be borne equiped with ESD protection; everyone from any technically creative species, to fight with compressed-air guns and wooden bullets.

Based on the question, I noticed you said "dragon like fauna" and while you might not accept magic as a solution. I will assume you have some kind of "non-human" threat that must be fought within these areas.
This makes most of the frame challenges moot, if you must fight there, then you must. Your world afterall.
In human vs Human I agree entirely with the other answers. But I will setup this based on the little clue you gave. "dragon like fauna" So there is something unlike the real world that exists here.
Well, first off I hope the humans have full ESD rated gear. No sparks, you can make equipment that will work in explosive areas. (We do it all the time, we even make electric motors that are Explosive atmosphere rated)
Now how would you fight? You would ventilate or improve the area you are going into. And you would likely use Drones.

Humans enter the area, in breathing gear I assume, and setup a protective area. Most of the other answers have dealt with weapons/tactics for within the EX-Atmosphere.
I would "flood" the area I was going into with a dense nonreactive gas (and pump the bad one out if I could) One that pushes away the other gas and gives my side a safe place to engage from. Ideally with a barrier incase one of my bullets causes a spark in the area outside of my inert gas region.

I have to assume this area is "inconsistent" in the EX-Atmosphere density. It is very rational that humans would simply bring sensors to read if the area is Explosive or not. I assume this would be done via an EX-rated Drones, that would map out the region.

I assume that there is a drawback to just blowing it up. Perhaps "treasure" is in the dragon's lair. :)

Frame Challenge: No one would fight to the death.
This is MAD on a very personal scale
Combat would be grappling, judo, wrestling or boxing.  Situations where opponents could be subdued but typically not killed.
If you're engaged in a fight to the death, either one-on-one or in a larger engagement, and you are (or your team is) going to lose, then there's no downside to striking a match.  You describe the setting as "near future", so you could even have a dead man's switch, where when your heartbeat stops, a pilot light flares to life and your killer gets immolated along with you.
As with MAD, the only safe lethal combat would be a decapitation strike that cannot be anticipated.

I think this is close enough to right, but I think it would be more right to say that combat would be ritual combat with agreed upon terms for what the winner and loser have to do, not nonlethal combat necessarily. If you win and take the region from me without my consent, whether you do it with phasers or fists, I can toss a flare in as I retreat and blow you up.

@gs - that assumes that all parties are content to engage in ritual combat.  Nonlethal combat doesn't require that your opponent accede, just that they're unwilling to die to take you with them.  I think ritual combat would make for a better story, though.

Ah, that's a good point. POWs as de facto human shields against punitive nuking, also.

I gotta disagree hard with this answer.

That's true for the fighting in such environment, but it seems implausible that any side would allow themselves in such situation.
The normal approach would be to burn the gas before entering. You might want to enter without that in order to hide your position, however you'd be hard pressed to leave quickly: if you are detected (or the enemy makes a sweeping search for you) the enemy will burn you instead of entering. If 2 such covert groups meet, however, mutual destruction is almost guaranteed.

@Frax - the answer was written using the assumption implied by the OP - the people fighting are for some reason compelled to do so in the explosive atmosphere.

Fight from somewhere else. The dangerous regions are the ultimate metaphorical enfilade: if you are in it and the enemy is not, you lose. Soldiers will avoid them at all costs.
By analogy to real history: soldiers wearing metal armor and carrying swords and spears will drown if they fight in deep water. What weapons do they fight with on our world where deep water is common, and how does the presence of deep water shape the battlefield?
You can make the soldiers fight in the dangerous region with various contrivances if your plot demands it - in which case I would agree with jdunlop more or less. But in general even if the fight is over something in the dangerous region itself, it will be a fight over who gets to control all metaphorical defilade positions in order to operate in the enfilade region unopposed.
Fishing rights go to the ancient army that controls the shore. Kaboom gas mining rights go to the futuristic army that controls the sky and skyline.

When my brother was in the army, he said that "Take the bullets out your guns and fix bayonets" was the scariest order you could be given on a modern battlefield, but sometimes it still happens... I imagine in this setting that is doubly true since it means you are probably charging through an explosive gas cloud and don't want anyone accidently setting it off.

@Nosajimiki The other thing to consider re: bayonet charges is that the goal of war is not to kill the enemy; that's just a side effect. If you are rapidly approaching the other guy's position with a pointy piece of metal, he is unlikely to stick around to get stabbed. Thus, you achieve your military objective (routing the enemy and/or taking his position) without having to actually kill the enemy. Bayonets save lives.

Frame challenge: It doesn’t matter
The gas can’t be in the whole atmosphere, because otherwise everything would be dying off every time there’s a thunderstorm or a volcanic eruption (also, look into the geophysics of volcanism, that provides a very easy and believable way to produce the type of terrain you describe if you handwave the gas itself). That means it’s confined to the ravines/trenches, which imposes two really important limitations:

The gas can’t be produced too rapidly, otherwise it would end up all over the surface of the planet and you’re back in the situation where thunderstorms are mass extinction events.
The ravines/trenches can’t be too common, otherwise there’s nowhere for complex life to develop (or settle if you’re dealing with some species not native to the world itself) and thus have no lifeforms to tell your story with.

This then solves your problem for you, because it means that everyone can just avoid the ravines/trenches. And maybe, once civilization gets advanced enough, there will be regular controlled burns to mitigate risk, and the ravines/trenches will just be an interesting bit of geography with some special safety rules around them.

To propel a projectile you can use, in alternative to gunpowder:

compressed air
high pressure steam
electromagnetism, like a coil-gun
mechanical advantage, like a slingshot, a trebuchet, an atlatl

Which one is better depends on your world and which vibe you want to give to it.

Maybe I could make this region sub terranean with an isolated atmosphere to account for the why hasn't it exploded already. Thanks

Interesting choices for mechanical advantage when "crossbow" is right there.

And the projector itself, of course, has to be non-sparking. And/or the objective hits has to be non-sparkling. The problem I have with this scenario is that you have to explain why this environment hasn't already blown itself up.

The elektro options are risky though, some worn down part creates a spark and boom. Otherwise what I had in mind

Examples: "Holman Projector" was a WW2 steam cannon, and the USS Vesuvius was a ship armed with three "dynamite guns" in fixed mounts pointing forwards.  These were straight compressed air, not explosive.

Never mind crossbow, a regular bow is far superior for most purposes. And in this context, it has the massive advantage that there are no moving metal parts, and arrows can be made without metal heads and still be highly effective.

Weaponize the Exploding Gas
What you'd really want to do is make the gas near your enemy blow up while you stay far enough away. So something like a compressed air gun with a charge designed to start an explosion on impact would be standard issue.
If the gas is so widespread that you can't get far enough away, then you have to answer the question "Why hasn't it blown up already just from other small heat sources?"
Iron or steel weapons still would have the problem of causing sparks occasionally when they strike, so that's no good. As well as any projectile that could spark when it strikes a rock (unless you're trying to ignite the gas near your target as per this answer).

Frame challenge: Igniting this terrain will be a standard part of tactics.
Fighting in this exploding terrain is foolishly dangerous. So a standard part of scouting a potential battlefield will be finding out where it is, and placing radio-controlled fireworks to ignite it (the OP said this is a near-future world). All sides in any conflict will do this, because it's cheap, easy and saves your troops from having to fight in a pointlessly dangerous environment.
That means that igniting terrain you intend to use will be an indication of where you intend to move your troops. Commanders will therefore use it to mislead the other side, by indicating that they intend to move somewhere which they actually have no interest in, or delaying igniting terrain until just before they enter it. They will also place scouts ready to ignite any terrain they don't intend to use, in case the enemy tries doing something unexpected.
Some overly brave junior commander will try a surprise attack through un-ignited terrain, and get himself blown up. After that, it is likely to become one of the things that commanders don't try to do, because it turns their own troops against them.

If, for the story, the troops must fight in these areas, anything that can create a spark is out. So they will basically be fighting with blunt, non-sparking objects, and armored with leather or synthetic fabrics that are resistant to static electricity. Otherwise, even crushing metal armor could create sparks and heat. If your gas was slightly less volatile, say it needed a sustained heat to get started, you could rule out firearms, since that would cross the threshold to create a boom. But most sparks would not be enough to set it off. Think thermite or firework sparklers. Simply touching them with a flame is not enough to set them off, but a sustained burn will eventually light it. You just need a gas that won't go off with a spark, but will with a gunshot.

Honestly, nothing much would change.
Your post implies the gasses are dangerous only in trenches and other "under the ground level" situations where the gas can accumulate enough to become volatile.
Which only means warfare would skip trenches and such places.
It would involve logistic more than weapon tech.
And for the occasions where it's necessary to fight in such places?
Going medieval with non-metallic weaponry would be the modern solution.
...unless you don't care about prisoners and just detonate the whole thing with a well aimed flint bullet from far away.
Again, logistic.

All things metal in your scenario are letha. As in can sparks- blow the situation up. Same goes for all projectiles that are non-soft or non-organic. If it can impact to damage humans it can strike a spark - kabloom.
The only way to be safe, is ropes - whips are dangeorus - and foams. As in Cannisters creating foams with various properties. Irritating foams, narcotic foams- gluey foams, foams to hide, luminescent foams to blind, foams to contains firesparks and extuinguish and evelop dangerous objects.
Also- bring your own firewall into the scenario, barricade and blow it all up when you think your safe - is always a option.

Soft metals like lead and brass won't spark, and is safe to use in explosive zones (Ex approved tools basically).

So, you guarantee that in the midst of battle that tool stays clean and you know you will not transfer momentum to iron on iron like a chainmail

My dear Pica, you forgot to mention that your wool cardigan would be the equivalent of a death sentence for everyone :)

Charge! No, not that way.. Boxing Gloves are on..

The other answers are all good, but here's another not-quite-as-good option: slings, slingshots, blowguns, catapults, etc.

You're thinking too small. This is free energy, and would get used. Something like a cross between a Davies lamp, catalitic converter, and a gas turbine would be one possibility to turn the gas into useful energy,  and then there's none left.
If it didn't get used up it would be utilised as a hypobaric weapon.
